transfer csv/parquet data from one s3 bucket to other s3 bucket with the help of pyspark
I am using spark cluster which is consisting of ec2 machines and now with the help of pyspark I want to transfer data from source S3 bucket to destination bucket in parquet format.both of the buckets have different IAM roles and bucket policies. I am setting spark AWS access key and secret key at hadoop level using this code
def set_s3_credentials(access_key, secret_key):
    hadoop_conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)

but I am getting this ERROR -

Error occurred: An error occurred while calling o56.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 8 times, most recent failure: Lost
task 0.7 in stage 1.0 (TID 8) (172.12.2.153 executor 0):
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
s3a://wayfinder-doceree-s3-customer-data/export/mx_submits_2024_06/part-00000-tid-1074794359726202293-9f504b1d-da56-4031-963b-be9f22348eb4-141340-1.c000.snappy.parquet:
getFileStatus on
s3a://wayfinder-doceree-s3-customer-data/export/mx_submits_2024_06/part-00000-tid-1074794359726202293-9f504b1d-da56-4031-963b-be9f22348eb4-141340-1.c000.snappy.parquet:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service:
Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID:
6C07ME6ZAV2B4XSA; S3 Extended Request ID:
Dx8EtSGjnYMl0Ld6kwSs9L9CMk0sdrDkzzdCSsXaG2KXk1uhC6iAIkly0mBCmB6rehqSuat0RlR0WHjPQlFkQQ==;
Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID:
Dx8EtSGjnYMl0Ld6kwSs9L9CMk0sdrDkzzdCSsXaG2KXk1uhC6iAIkly0mBCmB6rehqSuat0RlR0WHjPQlFkQQ==:403
Forbidden
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:255).

Sometimes I am getting 056.parquet in place of 056.showString. In my code I am first setting credentials for source bucket by using the above function and then reading my data from source bucket using spark.read.parquet() and am successfully able to read it in dataframe and use aggregate function like df.count() or see it using df.show().
But after that I am trying to change the credentials for destination bucket using the above function but after changing those credentials when I am trying to write or use df.show() the data it is showing me the exception.
Here is my code:
def copy_parquet_file():
    try:
        # Set and log source AWS credentials
        set_s3_credentials(source_aws_access_key_id, source_aws_secret_access_key)
        logging.info(f"Set source AWS credentials for bucket: '{source_bucket_name}'")
        # update_spark_conf(source_s3_conf)

        logging.info(f"Starting to copy file from bucket '{source_bucket_name}' key '{source_key}' to bucket '{destination_bucket_name}' key '{destination_key}'")
        hadoop_conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
        logging.info(f'Source bucket access_key: {hadoop_conf.get("fs.s3a.access.key")}')
        logging.info(f'Source bucket secret_key: {hadoop_conf.get("fs.s3a.secret.key")}')   

        # Read parquet file from source bucket using PySpark
        source_parquet_path = f"s3a://{source_bucket_name}/{source_key}"
        df = spark.read.parquet(source_parquet_path, header=True, multiLine=True, quote="\"", escape="\"")
        df = df.limit(100) 
        # df.printSchema()
        logging.info("Read source parquet file successfully.")

        # Set and log destination AWS credentials
        set_s3_credentials(dest_aws_access_key_id, dest_aws_secret_access_key)
        # update_spark_conf(destination_s3_conf)
        logging.info(f"Set destination AWS credentials for bucket: '{destination_bucket_name}'")
        
        logging.info(f'Destination bucket access_key: {hadoop_conf.get("fs.s3a.access.key")}')
        logging.info(f'Destination bucket secret_key: {hadoop_conf.get("fs.s3a.secret.key")}')

        # Write dataframe to destination bucket using PySpark
        destination_parquet_path = f"s3a://{destination_bucket_name}/{destination_key}"
        time.sleep(10)
        df.show()
        df.write.parquet(destination_parquet_path, mode='overwrite')
        logging.info(f'Copied {source_key} to {destination_key} successfully.')

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred: {e}") 

I want to transfer my data without such exceptions successfully.

can you use AWS Glue, its fast and easy. You can also leverage, visual ETL to do so?

Agree with you, but it is costly

The s3a connector supports "per bucket configuration"; this is how you set up different login details, policies etc for different buckets.

working through spark will still read every byte and write it back again. If you use the aws s3 cp command line tool it will do the COPY within the s3 store itself, which, if they are in the same region and if you can get authentication to work, is going to be way faster. Spark makes sense if you either have a large cluster of many workers or you want to do some kind of transformation

if you can't use the aws s3 command, I'd grab cloudstore and use its cloudup command to do the copy. It doesn't do in-s3 COPY operations, but there's a reasonable amount of optimisation for bulk copying data. a single process can generally generate enough IO to start overloading network connections, especially AWS PrivateLink.



I have to do it in pyspark only. I don't have these options. And also I have these two buckets in different region.

so use per-bucket settings. you won't get anywhere by trying to change hadoop config settings as you go along

Please explain me how to use per-bucket setting or in spark is there any other way of doing this.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/connecting.html#Using_Per-Bucket_Configuration_to_access_data_round_the_world
